# How to import all the images in a folder?

Tags: image-processing, image

[image][image: Jobs]

the source code is

```
imagePool = Map[With[{i = Import[#]}, {i, Mean[Flatten[N[i[[1, 1]]], 1]]}] &, FileNames["Pool/*.jpg"]];

closeMatch[c_] := RandomChoice[Take[SortBy[imagePool, Norm[c - #[[2]]] &], 20]][[1]];

Grid[Reverse[Map[closeMatch, Import["MasterImage.tif"][[1, 1]], {2}]], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

I don't quite understand....
.
PICTURE FROM:http://www.zhihu.com/topic/19559256

Comment: This seems very broad. Also, the code will not run as pasted. Can you ask a  more specific question?

Comment: Related: http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/05/02/making-photo-mosaics/

Comment: @YvesKlett actually that's why I am asking here in stackexchange...I have a pool of pictures  and I want to use them to make phtomosaics using mathematica. I want to know the certain function and how to import them to mathematica.

Comment: The blog entry posted by @MichaelE2 is a really good start. If you can narrow down your question to specific points, then you might get good answers. A overall generic code review is not very appealing in general.

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks for your suggestion.I 'm new in stackexchange and it may take some time before  I get used to some basic rules.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks.not easy for me to fully understand,though:(

Comment: The code (in the Q) won't work. Eg. `Import["ExampleData/spikey.tiff"][[1, 1]]` gives an error. It probably should be `ImageData@Import["file.tiff"]`. Then the last line replaces each pixel by one of 20 images that are close color matches. It won't produce the SJ pic, b/c that pic is not segmented by pixels (there are large and small rectangles). The blog process (as I recall) is to set up a grid of random images and then to randomly switch an image and keep the change if the mosaic is closer. For a small number of pixel-blocks it's fairly efficient. So start with a small "master" picture.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Just a reminder: in earlier versions `Image` was not atomic and one could extract parts without `ImageData`.

Comment: @YvesKlett I'm sorry my question was off-topic.When I copy the code to mathematica note-book I couldn't make it work ,either.I have trouble in importing a image pool .I tried many different ways,some times the images themselves shows,sometimes only the path could be seen and I 'm confused.What's the difference?...Maybe I'm being stupid when I asked this question,what should I do with this question now?I seem to be in trouble ask more questions.

Comment: Sean,  you are not in trouble at all...  please go ahead and ask if you are looking for help! Take a look at the site first to get an idea how this site works - concise,  clear questions have a pretty good chance of attracting answers.

Comment: @YvesKlett well，thank u for your advice！